# Get all the Distribution List from your outlook 2007

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to get all the distribution list that I created in my outlook 2007 without actually going through all my contacts.

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried googling but didn't see anything that I could use. Im in the dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this code and let me know if it works for you. Basically, it pulls all of your global address contacts (with additional information) from outlook and puts them on a new sheet.
Open up the vba module, and in the task bar choose "TOOLS" (Next to "RUN"). Next, select "REFERENCES". Go down until you see "MICROSOFT OUTLOOK 16.0 Object Library" and check it. Hopefully that makes sense.

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNameSpace     As Namespace
Dim olAddrList      As AddressList
Dim olAddrEntry     As AddressEntry
Dim olExchgnUser    As ExchangeUser
Dim sh              As Worksheet
Dim lCnt            As Long

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olAddrList = olNameSpace.AddressLists("Global Address List")


Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add


With sh
    .Cells(1, 1) = "NAME"
    .Cells(1, 2) = "FIRST NAME"
    .Cells(1, 3) = "LAST NAME"
    .Cells(1, 4) = "ALIAS"
    .Cells(1, 5) = "JOB TITLE"
    .Cells(1, 6) = "DEPARTMENT"
End With


lCnt = 2

For Each olAddrEntry In olAddrList.AddressEntries


    Set olExchgnUser = olAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser

    On Error Resume Next

    With olExchgnUser
        sh.Cells(lCnt, 1) = .Name
        sh.Cells(lCnt, 2) = .FirstName
        sh.Cells(lCnt, 3) = .LastName
        sh.Cells(lCnt, 4) = .Alias
        sh.Cells(lCnt, 5) = .JobTitle
        sh.Cells(lCnt, 6) = .Department
    End With

    Application.StatusBar = "Processing contact " & lCnt & "..."

    If Err.Number = 0 Then lCnt = lCnt + 1
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

Next olAddrEntry
Application.StatusBar = ""

MsgBox "Outlook Extraction Complete",vbinformation,"Outlook Extraction"

End Sub
```

Comment: By the way, the Application.Status Bar property lets the user now the percentage of completion of a macro that may take some time to completely process.

Comment: I got a run-time error 1004. Method'This Workbook' of object '_global' failed. Can you give any instructions (amateur at this)

Comment: I forgot to include that in my post. Open up the vba module, and in the task bar choose "TOOLS" (Next to "RUN"). Next, select "REFERENCES". Go down until you see "MICROSOFT OUTLOOK 16.0 Object Library" and check it. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I dont see MICROSOFT OUTLOOK 16.0 Object Library in my references. I only  see the MICROSOFT OUTLOOK 12.0 Object Library

Comment: That should do the job. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: no I got the same error run-time error 1004. Method'This Workbook' of object '_global' failed

Comment: Is it highlighting a certain line of code as the error? It works on my station but I am using Outlook 365. It should still theoretically work, regardless of outlook 2007 and 365.  That global variable error is definitely linked to the reference issue.Take a look at this link-it may help you. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other-mso_2007/how-do-i-export-email-addresses-in-the-to-field-to/cae25c2b-fbad-4467-a186-24d4c7b5b3d2